# Making an ASCII hourglass using asterisks

Tags: java, loops, nested-loops, ascii-art, nested-for-loop

I know it's been asked but I'm having some hard time understanding other programs and nested loops, if someone has a trick to follow nested loops and making a shape with asterisks I would like to know because it really got me confused.

Here is the code I wrote after many many tries and experiments:

```java
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
int userentry = input.nextInt();
for (int i = 0; i < userentry - 1; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (int j = userentry - 1; j >= i; j--) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
for (int i = 0; i < userentry; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < i + 1; k++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

The output for the number entry 3 for example goes like this, i'm having trouble with the spacing:

```
***
 **
 *
  **
   ***
```

I would really appreciate someone who can help me with my program and explain me the algorithm and how can I make more patterns.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine a *coordinate plane* in a range `[-n, n]` both vertically and horizontally. You can use two nested *for loops* and one *if else statement* to print it out:

```java
int n = 3;
for (int i = -n; i <= n; i++) {
    for (int j = -n; j <= n; j++)
        if (i == 0 || j == 0)
            System.out.print("*");
        else
            System.out.print("-");
    System.out.println();
}
```

Coordinate plane:

```
---*---
---*---
---*---
*******
---*---
---*---
---*---
```

To print the *hourglass* you only need to change the *if else statement*:

```java
int n = 3;
for (int i = -n; i <= n; i++) {
    for (int j = -n; j <= n; j++)
        if (Math.abs(i) < Math.abs(j))
            System.out.print(" ");
        else
            System.out.print("*");
    System.out.println();
}
```

Hourglass:

```
*******
 ***** 
  ***  
   *   
  ***  
 ***** 
*******
```

---

<sup>See also: [How to print ASCII patterns in C# but using Java syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67963518/16235843)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can visualize a *hourglass* as a matrix of numbers in a range `[-n, n]` inclusive, where each point is:

```
m[i][j] = Math.abs(i) - Math.abs(j);
```

If `n = 3`, then this matrix looks like this:

```
  0  1  2  3  2  1  0
 -1  0  1  2  1  0 -1
 -2 -1  0  1  0 -1 -2
 -3 -2 -1  0 -1 -2 -3
 -2 -1  0  1  0 -1 -2
 -1  0  1  2  1  0 -1
  0  1  2  3  2  1  0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVA9T8NADN3zK6xMF0RuYbvyMSCGDlWHsiEGJznSu96X7pxKCPW3h2toA0OF4MmSref3bNka91j7IJ3uduOobPCRQGeSD6QMTxQlWr50tJmqRVGEoTGqhdZgSrBC5eCjgIwTnwgpp71XHdjcZdmoXP/yChj7VJ3ERyhH4OAObhYzNe/hEV0vH41PsmO1uwZXzaIzuMXAVkhbIbBJF/pByh1TUN//b@5f5//UPft1o5k@7lJwCxoeoIQcAsorKH/xvvn4hO2Wbd4TScv9QEKE/DCqLhx0Fk83fTv4ZDCOVdXXKw/FYRw/AQ)

```java
int n = 3;
IntStream.rangeClosed(-n, n)
        .map(Math::abs)
        .peek(i -> IntStream.rangeClosed(-n, n)
                .map(Math::abs)
                .mapToObj(j -> i < j ? "  " : "* ")
                .forEach(System.out::print))
        .forEach(i -> System.out.println());
```

Output:

```
* * * * * * * 
  * * * * *   
    * * *     
      *       
    * * *     
  * * * * *   
* * * * * * *
```

---

<sup>See also: [How to draw a staircase with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66772762/15402945)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Because each character in the font used for input/output/code all have the same width, you have to decrease each iteration by 2, like:

```
****
 **
 **
****
```

or

```
*****
 ***
  *
 ***
*****
```

instead of one.
For spacing, use the following:

```
for (int i = userentry; i > 0; i -= 2) {
  for (int j = 0; j < (userentry - i) / 2; j++) System.out.print(" ");
  for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) System.out.print("*");
  for (int j = 0; j < (userentry - i) / 2; j++) System.out.print(" ");
  System.out.println();
}
for (int i = (userentry % 2 == 0 ? 2 : 3); i <= userentry; i += 2) {
  for (int j = 0; j < (userentry - i) / 2; j++) System.out.print(" ");
  for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) System.out.print("*");
  for (int j = 0; j < (userentry - i) / 2; j++) System.out.print(" ");
  System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code

```java
class HelloWorld {
  static void pattern(int rows_no) {
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 1; i <= rows_no; i++) {
      for (k = 1; k < i; k++)
        System.out.print(" ");
      for (j = i; j <= rows_no; j++)
        System.out.print("*" + " ");

      System.out.println();
    }
    for (i = rows_no - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
      for (k = 1; k < i; k++)
        System.out.print(" ");
      for (j = i; j <= rows_no; j++)
        System.out.print("*" + " ");
      System.out.println();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int rows_no = 3;
    pattern(rows_no);
  }
}
```

Which gives the output as:

```
* * * 
 * * 
  * 
 * * 
* * *
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print an hourglass, you have to print two triangles, one erect and the other inverted (note that the tips of both triangles is common asterisk).

This may be done using the code given below...

```java
class HourGlass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        int userentry = input.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < userentry; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int j = userentry - 1; j >= i; j--) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            for (int k = userentry - i; k > 1; k--) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < userentry; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < userentry - i - 1; k++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < i; k++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

This prints on entering `3`...

```
*****
 ***
  *
 ***
*****
```